# MVC: Lean controller vs injecting the repository?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture

The controller should ideally be free from domain logic right?
How does that match up with injecting a repository class into it like in nerd dinner?

If you are one of those who don't inject the repo into the controller, how do you name your app/domain layer classes that contains the code that references the repository accessors and does the work with the model classes? Or do you split it up further? How?

**Added to the question:**

For the above question, could you please consider theese three scenarios:

1. Retrieving a model and returning a view
2. Recieving a form edit to validate and persist to a database
3. Order processing

I hope this addition can make the question clearer such that we can refer to common types of scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We inject the repository *interfaces* into our controllers, so our controller doesn't care about domain logic implementation. Our IoC container takes care of determining which class to use as an implementation for each repository interface.

Comment: Surely you are specifying an interface in the controller, but injecting a concrete implementation of that interface via your container.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: Precisely. The point being that the controller's code remains free of domain logic.

Comment: I wasn't really thinking about new vs injection but rather if repository+models should be used directly from the controller or wrapped in a domain layer. What's considered as good practice?

Comment: @Carl R: Our repository interfaces work strictly on POCOs that represent domain-level models, so we're not dealing with any data-layer classes in the controller itself. The implementation of the repository interface concerns itself with translating the domain-level model into something representing our data-level model.

Comment: That sounds fine for CRUD, but for order handling or other multi-step operations it sounds like the controller starts orchestrating multiple POCOS and workflow (ie domain logic)? (Or something is missing from your description.)

Comment: @Carl R: You're right: the technique I'm describing is just for operations where a repository interface "makes sense." For other actions (i.e. "Merge these two objects"), we inject utility interfaces (whose implementations may access the data layer directly or may invoke other utilities and repositories). Sometimes even our repository implementations have quite a bit of additional logic happening behind the scenes. The point is that the controller needn't care about any of that. It's just invoking a method to add/retrieve/merge/whatever using IDs or domain-level POCOs as arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Data Access Logic != Domain Logic

Injecting a controller with a Repository is fine if you are trying to do DDD.

I name things ElephantRepository, ElephantService or ElephantQuery depending on the pattern I'm using at the moment.

---

I would be really interested to see an MVC application that didn't access a repository/service/dal layer from the controller.  ;)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by DAL != Domain logic. It's obvious that an apple isn't a banana, but what's your point? :)